# Помогите разобраться с папками сайта

Tags: php, yii2, apache, apache2

Товарищ попросил перенести сайт. Я перенес папку `public_html`, но в ней находятся только статические файлы. Сами файлы движка находятся в папке `private`, которая лежит на одном уровне с `public_html`.

Из-за этого когда я открываю сайт - мне говорит, что не может найти файлы движка. Как мне это исправить? Как вообще добраться к папке `private`? ]

Прошу помощи, так как первый раз с таким столкнулся

P.S. Движок сайта - yii2

Вот код index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Comment: можете прикрепить структуру папок сайта, если не ошибаюсь в yii2 все публичные файлы в папке `web`.

Comment: Следите за действиями с главного index.php и url-менеджером. Обычно всё в web, скорее всего где-то в конфиге прописан путь к папке private.

Comment: в конфиге не может быть, так как он подключается позже (код файла выложил в вопросе)